# Android Notification Bar icon, is there a way to lock the location of the icon?

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-notification-bar

I currently have a service driven notification appearing.  I am trying to figure out if there is a way to lock the location at which the icon appears.  I want to ensure that the icon is always in the same location on the Notification bar, no matter how many notifications appear before or after it.  Ideally, I would like to lock it on the right side of the clock and Wifi icons.  I am in Ice Cream Sandwich. Does anyone know if this is possible?  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Notification.when propperty.
You can locate it the first or the last using really high values (long.Max) or really small ones (-long.Max).
But we are allways talking about the left group.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot control the position of your `Notification` in the status or system bar, sorry.

Second, at least on phones, your `Notification` will be on the left, away from "the clock and Wifi icons".